# Custom combobox style

Tags: c#, wpf

So after few days learning WPF im trying to make custom style for my ComboBox. I want to set border with content width to fill all unused space between border and drop down button. After I fix this I will start with drop down list with items.

### Result:

[image]

### Code:

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox">
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <DockPanel>
               <Border x:Name="bg" BorderBrush="Yellow" Background="HotPink" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="0" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                  <ContentPresenter
                        Name="ContentSite"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False" 
                        Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                        ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                        Margin="3,3,23,3"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
               </Border>
               <Button x:Name="dropBtn" Width="20" DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                  <Path VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Width="10"
                        Height="8"
                        Data="M0,0 L0,2 L4,6 L8,2 L8,0 L4,4 z"
                        Stretch="Fill"
                        Fill="HotPink"/>
               </Button>
            </DockPanel>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders I will keep this in mind. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Move button before border* in your DockPanel so that it becomes last child of your panel.

Then set `LastChildFill` to `True` on DockPanel.

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
   <Button x:Name="dropBtn" Width="20" DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Right">
       <Path VerticalAlignment="Center"
             Width="10"
             Height="8"
             Data="M0,0 L0,2 L4,6 L8,2 L8,0 L4,4 z"
             Stretch="Fill"
             Fill="HotPink"/>
   </Button>
   <Border x:Name="bg" BorderBrush="Yellow" Background="HotPink"
           BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="0" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
      <ContentPresenter
             Name="ContentSite"
             IsHitTestVisible="False" 
             Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
             ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
             ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
             Margin="3,3,23,3"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
   </Border>
</DockPanel>
```

As per documentation of [LastChildFill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dockpanel.lastchildfill%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the last child element
>   within a DockPanel stretches to fill the remaining available space.